# Subscribing to events in Android

Tags: android

I'm getting into Android development, and I want to be able to run a popup dialog or notification whenever the user sets an alarm(like in an alarm clock). Could anyone point me in the right direction of what to look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of "alarm" apps for Android, including dozens of different pre-installed ones for different devices. Approximately none of them support any sort of "event" that is published when users set an alarm in one.

You are welcome to contact the developers of various alarm apps and ask them to expose some sort of documented and supported API for what you seek.

Comment: There's no system wide event I can subscribe to, in other words? My thinking was that my lock screen knows there's an alarm set, so that'd be what I would be looking for.

Comment: @RushTea: "There's no system wide event I can subscribe to, in other words?" -- correct. "My thinking was that my lock screen knows there's an alarm set" -- at most, only for the device's own alarm app. You are welcome to look at API Level 21's `getNextAlarmClock()` method on `AlarmManager` and see if that reports what the lock screen gets.

Comment: That makes alot of sense. Oh well, guess I'll have to schedule my own alarms then. Thank you very much for clearing this up neatly and quickly.